# $n$-digit prime mid point for maximum pairs of $n$-digit primes

Tags: prime-numbers

Has anyone found which $n$-digit prime (or primes) is the midpoint for the 
maximum number of pairs of other $n$-digit primes?  For four pairs $47$ is the
midpoint for $(5,89), (11,83), (23,71)$, and $(41,53)$.  I searched "balanced
primes" with no success.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  What is fixed and what varies?

Comment: I think that already for, lets say , $n=9$ , we can have plenty of pairs. I do not think we can find the "best" prime for, lets say, $n=50$ and neither the possible number of pairs.

Comment: You are forgetting the point about the number of digits for the midpoint and for ALL other pairs of primes with the SAME number of digits.  Can we have n=9 for a mere 2-digit prime??  We may have that many for a 3-digit prime, and perhaps three different midpoints each being a midpoint for the SAME number of pairs of other 3-digit primes.  The only thing that is fixed is the number of digits for the primes being considered.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot $n$ is the number of digits, and the number of possible pairs will soon "explode" with increasing $n$

Comment: Granted that  for n=9 there will be primes as midpoints for many pairs of primes.  Has anyone bothered to find out what is the maximum number of pairs with nine digits?  If they explode, perhaps this has frighten anyone from searching.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot $n=9$ is surely feasible, $n=15$ with massive computation as well. Perhaps, we can even get to $n=20$, but I doubt that we can count the solutions for $n=50$ , even for a single prime number , let alone for all prime numbers to find the champion.

Comment: So, so true, and I guess that's why no one has gotten the petaflop machine ready for hot action.  File this question under "a threat to national security."

Comment: It seems to me that one could do a search by using even
semiprimes that will get one at the median of the n-digit
range.  So,  for 3-digit numbers, start at 2*271=542
then go backward to 2*269, 2*263..and forward to
2*277, 2*281..to  find the maximum number of pairs.